# ${f(x) = x^2 + x + 1}$ is continuous on ${\mathbb{R}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity, epsilon-delta

I need help finding the limit of the function ${f(x) = x^2 + x + 1}$ as ${x\rightarrow c}$ for any ${c \in \mathbb{R}}$. So far I have used the limit definition and triangle inequality up to this point.

$${|(x^2+x+1)-(c^2+c+1)|=|x^2-c^2+x-c|\leq|x^2-c^2|+|x-c|}$$

I do not know how to handle the $|x^2-c^2|$ part within the limit definition.

Comment: Just editted the question, please make sure it's still as you intend it - also, for future questions - you can refer to https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for help with formatting the Mathjax

Comment: Note $|x^2-c^2|=|x-c||x+c|$; by the way, any polynomial function is continuous

Comment: Thank you! It still fits my intentions!

Comment: I did notice that after posting, I still am having trouble though handling the inequalities with the limit definition. @J.W.Tanner

Comment: Alternatively, you've surely already encountered the fact that $\lim (A+B) = \lim(A)+\lim(B)$ whenever each of the terms exists and is finite. So then you can work with $x^2,x,1$ individually.

Answer (score 2):

Let $ c\ge 0 $ and $ x $ such that
$$|x-c|<1$$

Given an $\epsilon>0$, we must find $ \delta>0 $ satisfying

$$|x-c|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$$

or

$$|x-c|<\delta \implies |x-c||x+c+1|<\epsilon$$

but
$$|x-c|<1\implies c-1<x<c+1$$
$$\implies 2c<x+c+1<2c+2$$
$$\implies |x+c+1|<2(c+1)$$
thus, to realise the condition $$|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$$
It is sufficient to have
$$|x-c|<1 \text{ and } 2|x-c|(c+1)<\epsilon$$
or
$$|x-c|<1 \text{ and } |x-c|<\frac{\epsilon}{2(c+1)}$$

So, we can take
$$\delta=\min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{2(c+1)})$$

You can do the same if $ c<0.$

Answer (score 1):

We fix a point $c$, and show that the given function is continuous in $c$.

- Let $\epsilon>0$.

> (We search some $\delta=\delta(\epsilon)$ such that the ball centered in $c$ and radius $\delta$ is mapped by $f$ into the ball centered in $f(c)$ and radius $\epsilon$. For this we take a break and swear we will take some $\delta<1$. But then we estimate on some other piece of paper $|x^2-c^2|+|x-c|=|x-c|\cdot|x+c|+|x-c|\le|x-c|\cdot(|x|+|c|+1)\le|x-c|\cdot(|c|+1+|c|+1)$. This estimation is the essence. Now we can...)

- Consider / set $\displaystyle \delta$ to be the minimal value between $1$ and  $\frac\epsilon{2(|c|+1)}$.
- Let $x$ be such that $|x-c|< \delta$. Then we have:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
  |f(x)-f(c)|
  &=|(x^2+x+1)-(c^2+c+1)|
  \\
  &=|(x^2-c^2)+(x-c)|
  \\
  &\le
  |x^2-c^2|+|x-c|
  \\
  &=|x-c|\cdot|x+c|+|x-c|
  \\
  &\le|x-c|\cdot(|x|+|c|+1)
  \\
  &\le|x-c|\cdot(|c|+1+|c|+1)\text{ since $\delta<1$}
  \\
  &<\delta\cdot(|c|+1+|c|+1)
  \\
  &\le
  \epsilon\ .
  \end{aligned}
  $$

So we have shown by definition...

$\square$

(Note that the hidden estimation is the receipt to chose $\delta$, and exactly the same estimation finishes the proof.)